# Como convertir los datos en unicode QT

Tags: c++, qt

Normalmente cuando quiero convertir el texto a string hago lo siguiente:

```
QString::fromUtf16((ushort*)buffer);
```

Pero hay alguna manera de convertir mi buffer(datos) a unicode?

Comment: Hola Omar, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. Desafortunadamente este sitio no es un sustituto de Google, por lo que tu pregunta deberás resolverla usando un buscador o en la documentación de Qt. Te informo además que el código que coloques aquí debe ser el que te presente algún problema y debe mostrar tus esfuerzos para resolverlo. Si quieres saber como funciona esta comunidad sigue este enlace [http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no es un problema, solo que el usuario no ha leído el manual.

Comment: Yo la veo como pregunta legítima. Expresa que no entiende exáctamente qué es Unicode (estoy preparando una respuesta ahora).

Comment: @Peregring-lk el historial de preguntas de Omar Alami expone que el tiempo dedicado a estudiarse la API de Qt se puede medir fácilmente en minutos...

Comment: Ya... lo sé, pero bueno, las codificaciones de carácteres nunca están bien explicadas (yo después de tantos años, todavía hay detalles que no llego a entender bien). Aunque Omar Alami se lea más y mejor la documentación de Qt, podría haber hecho la misma pregunta porque esto nunca llega a entenderse del todo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Los datos nunca están en "`Unicode`". Los datos están en `UTF-8`, `UTF-16`, `UTF-32`, `UCS-2`, o cualquier formato binario que **implemente** `Unicode`. `Unicode` es un estándar que asigna a cada carácter posible un número.

Ese estándar debe ser implementado por un formato de codificación como `UTF-8`, por ejemplo.

Cada formato de codificación transforma a binario los valores `Unicode` de manera diferente. Es decir, la representación binaria de una cadena `Unicode` cualquiera como `Vé por allí ☛`, será diferente en `UTF-8` y `UTF-16`.

Si el `buffer` se llena con valores que proceden de una base de datos o de la entrada del usuario, debes saber en qué codificación devuelve la base de datos dichos datos (si `UTF-8` o `UTF-16`), o en qué codificación te está dando datos el usuario por la entrada estándar, por ejemplo.

Una vez que sepas el formato de los datos devueltos, esos mismos datos deberían estar guardados sin cambios dentro del `buffer`. Si tu `buffer` contiene datos en `UTF-8`, entonces debes llamar a `fromUtf8()`, y si están en `UTF-16`, entonces a `fromUtf16()`.

En cualquier caso, la frase "convertir a `Unicode`" no tiene sentido porque `Unicode` es un estándar, y no nada que se pueda "guardar".

Fundamentalmente, si `fromUtf16()` te está dando resultados erróneos o extraños, es porque el `buffer` no está en `UTF-16`. Es decir, tienes que rastrear el origen de los datos del `buffer` para saber qué codificación tendrán (a lo mejor ni siquiera es una codificación `Unicode`, sino `ISO-8859-15`, que no es compatible a nivel binario con `UTF-8` por ejemplo).